# Check password strength - Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, passwords

How do I implement checking password strength to my PHP code?  It shows this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function strongpass::check(), 1 passed in C:\newxampp\htdocs\fyp\index.php on line 8 and exactly 2 expected in C:\newxampp\htdocs\fyp\strongpass.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\newxampp\htdocs\fyp\index.php(8): strongpass->check('asdgasdfsadfasd') #1 {main} thrown in C:\newxampp\htdocs\fyp\strongpass.php on line 7

```
class strongpass{
public function check($password,$user){
$denum_pass = strtr($password,'5301!','seoll');
$word_file = '/usr/share/dict/words'; // here is my dictionary
$lc_user = strtolower($user);
$lc_pass = strtolower($password);
$response = "OK";

//password that can't be same as username or reversed username
else if (($user == $password) || ($password == strrev($user))||
(denum_pass == $user) || ($denum_pass == strrev($user))){
$response = " Password cannot be same with username.";}

//password that doesn't contain any word in dictionary
else if (is_readable($word_file)){
if ($fh = fopen($word_file,'r')){
$found = false;
while (! ($found || feof($fh))) { 
$word = preg_quote(trim(strtolower(fgets($fh,1024))),'/');
if (preg_match("/$word/",$lc_pass) || preg_match("/$word/",$denum_pass)){
$found = true;}}
fclose($fh);
if ($found){
$response = 'Password is based on a dictionary word.';}}}
return $response; } }
```

The class is used like this:

```
$user = ""; if(isset($_POST["password"])){ 
$password = $_POST["password"]; 
include_once("strongpass.php"); 
$strongpass = new strongpass(); 
$response = $strongpass->check($password);
if($response != "OK"){ 
    $status = $response; 
} else { 
    $status = "Password is strong so parsing can continue here."; 
    
}
```

Comment: `else if (($user == $password)` You're starting with `else if`? Where's the `if`? (Nice code indentation would be nice, too)

Comment: Error is self explanatory, show how you call this function.  After that is fixed there will be other errors.

Comment: @brombeer i actually did  started with IF , there is the parts where is the code couldn't run it

Comment: @AbraCadaver like this ?
$password = "";
$status = "";
$user = "";
if(isset($_POST["password"])){
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 include_once("strongpass.php");
 $strongpass = new strongpass();
 $response = $strongpass->check($password);
 if($response != "OK"){
  $status = $response;
 } else {
  $status = "Password is strong so parsing can continue here.";
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

`strongpass->check('asdgasdfsadfasd')`
It looks like you're only passing the `$password` and no `$user` to the check method.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the method to require `$password` and `$user` arguments:

```
public function check($password,$user){
```

But you only pass `$password`:

```
$response = $strongpass->check($password);
```

So pass `$user` as well:

```
$response = $strongpass->check($password, $user);
```

However, I don't know how it will work with:

```
$password = "";
$status = ""; 
$user = "";
```

Comment: I not sure how it works tho cause I'm following youtube tutorial..

Comment: Don't use that tutorial if that is the code that they present.

Comment: i see , do you have any recommendation for this cause I have to do a password strength checker which also check password that doesn't contain dictionary word inside

Comment: i had done length, uppercase, lowercase and numbers. Just need 2 more